# What is the best way to itterate over key value pairs nested in an index using javascript?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, data-transform

I am trying to sort sets of associated key value pairs. They look like this:

`{"word":"a","votes":9326,"userMade":"FALSE","limiter":"FALSE"},`
But organized into labeled subsets of preferably a string or perhaps an index if necessary.

The data-set is a vote-per-use table of most used english words being parsed into pages.
I will be appending them as text to other html elements due to the constraints my use case, makes it a bit tricky, however, for an example I could work with a simple `console.log` of the page value followed by the `console.log` of every word value stored within that page. I need the order preserved. so probably indexed. I will also need to be able to sort each page by the votes value, but I think I can figure the rest out for that.

I have found tutorials on how to search through key-value pairs, but I cannot find how to do all of the following with one solution:

- A: access the value of word
- B: maintain the order of the data-set, allowing me to append them to the matching html element
- C: allows me the opportunity to change which set of elements I am appending to when i have finished looping through a single member of the parent index (the one recording the page)

I imagine it is some combination of for/of and for/in, but I'm getting a headache. Please help?

addl info:
function would run at app startup or when the dataset being examined is changed.
function would take a large dataset filled with around 200 page number values, each with 60+ sets of data like the one listed above, the contents of a single page index for example:

```
{"word":"a","votes":9326,"userMade":"FALSE","limiter":"FALSE"},
{"word":"aaron","votes":4129,"userMade":"FALSE","limiter":"FALSE"},
{"word":"abandoned","votes":1289,"userMade":"FALSE","limiter":"FALSE"},
{"word":"abc","votes":5449,"userMade":"FALSE","limiter":"FALSE"},
{"word":"aberdeen","votes":641,"userMade":"FALSE","limiter":"FALSE"},
{"word":"abilities","votes":2210,"userMade":"FALSE","limiter":"FALSE"},
{"word":"ability","votes":7838,"userMade":"FALSE","limiter":"FALSE"},
{"word":"able","votes":8649,"userMade":"FALSE","limiter":"FALSE"},
{"word":"aboriginal","votes":1837,"userMade":"FALSE","limiter":"FALSE"},
{"word":"abortion","votes":3232,"userMade":"FALSE","limiter":"FALSE"},
{"word":"about","votes":9295,"userMade":"FALSE","limiter":"FALSE"},
{"word":"above","votes":8818,"userMade":"FALSE","limiter":"FALSE"},
{"word":"abraham","votes":867,"userMade":"FALSE","limiter":"FALSE"},
{"word":"abroad","votes":4969,"userMade":"FALSE","limiter":"FALSE"},
{"word":"abs","votes":2415,"userMade":"FALSE","limiter":"FALSE"},
{"word":"absence","votes":4934,"userMade":"FALSE","limiter":"FALSE"},
{"word":"absent","votes":2937,"userMade":"FALSE","limiter":"FALSE"},
{"word":"absolute","votes":5251,"userMade":"FALSE","limiter":"FALSE"},
{"word":"absolutely","votes":5936,"userMade":"FALSE","limiter":"FALSE"},
{"word":"absorption","votes":285,"userMade":"FALSE","limiter":"FALSE"},
{"word":"abstract","votes":7946,"userMade":"FALSE","limiter":"FALSE"},
{"word":"abstracts","votes":1907,"userMade":"FALSE","limiter":"FALSE"},
{"word":"abuse","votes":7238,"userMade":"FALSE","limiter":"FALSE"},
{"word":"academic","votes":7917,"userMade":"FALSE","limiter":"FALSE"},
{"word":"academics","votes":1706,"userMade":"FALSE","limiter":"FALSE"},
{"word":"academy","votes":6755,"userMade":"FALSE","limiter":"FALSE"},
{"word":"acc","votes":6469,"userMade":"FALSE","limiter":"FALSE"},
{"word":"accent","votes":1020,"userMade":"FALSE","limiter":"FALSE"},
{"word":"accept","votes":7547,"userMade":"FALSE","limiter":"FALSE"},
{"word":"acceptable","votes":4907,"userMade":"FALSE","limiter":"FALSE"},
{"word":"acceptance","votes":7273,"userMade":"FALSE","limiter":"FALSE"},
{"word":"accepted","votes":7684,"userMade":"FALSE","limiter":"FALSE"},
{"word":"accepting","votes":1789,"userMade":"FALSE","limiter":"FALSE"},
{"word":"accepts","votes":1535,"userMade":"FALSE","limiter":"FALSE"},
{"word":"access","votes":9031,"userMade":"FALSE","limiter":"FALSE"},
{"word":"accessed","votes":2932,"userMade":"FALSE","limiter":"FALSE"},
{"word":"accessibility","votes":5702,"userMade":"FALSE","limiter":"FALSE"},
{"word":"accessible","votes":5662,"userMade":"FALSE","limiter":"FALSE"},
{"word":"accessing","votes":2096,"userMade":"FALSE","limiter":"FALSE"},
{"word":"accessories","votes":8875,"userMade":"FALSE","limiter":"FALSE"},
{"word":"accessory","votes":5661,"userMade":"FALSE","limiter":"FALSE"},
{"word":"accident","votes":5664,"userMade":"FALSE","limiter":"FALSE"},
{"word":"accidents","votes":2991,"userMade":"FALSE","limiter":"FALSE"},
{"word":"accommodate","votes":1807,"userMade":"FALSE","limiter":"FALSE"},
{"word":"accommodation","votes":8059,"userMade":"FALSE","limiter":"FALSE"},
{"word":"accommodations","votes":3885,"userMade":"FALSE","limiter":"FALSE"},
{"word":"accompanied","votes":2532,"userMade":"FALSE","limiter":"FALSE"},
{"word":"accompanying","votes":664,"userMade":"FALSE","limiter":"FALSE"},
{"word":"accomplish","votes":1070,"userMade":"FALSE","limiter":"FALSE"},
{"word":"accomplished","votes":2419,"userMade":"FALSE","limiter":"FALSE"},
{"word":"accordance","votes":6434,"userMade":"FALSE","limiter":"FALSE"},
{"word":"according","votes":8282,"userMade":"FALSE","limiter":"FALSE"},
{"word":"accordingly","votes":3003,"userMade":"FALSE","limiter":"FALSE"},
{"word":"account","votes":8996,"userMade":"FALSE","limiter":"FALSE"},
{"word":"accountability","votes":3029,"userMade":"FALSE","limiter":"FALSE"},
{"word":"accounting","votes":7459,"userMade":"FALSE","limiter":"FALSE"},
{"word":"accounts","votes":7507,"userMade":"FALSE","limiter":"FALSE"},
{"word":"accreditation","votes":1605,"userMade":"FALSE","limiter":"FALSE"},
{"word":"accredited","votes":3027,"userMade":"FALSE","limiter":"FALSE"},
{"word":"accuracy","votes":6779,"userMade":"FALSE","limiter":"FALSE"},
{"word":"accurate","votes":6427,"userMade":"FALSE","limiter":"FALSE"},
{"word":"accurately","votes":1493,"userMade":"FALSE","limiter":"FALSE"},
{"word":"accused","votes":2853,"userMade":"FALSE","limiter":"FALSE"},
{"word":"acdbentity","votes":1389,"userMade":"FALSE","limiter":"FALSE"},
```

and the output would ultimately append the value paired with each word to a specific button through iteration, but also sorted by the page value.

each page is a set of buttons in a 3d object that looks like this:

[image: screenshot 3d object]

the text is appended to each button which in turn is a 3d object embeded in an html object using aframe. I can make the appending code.

Comment: so, that's one item in an array? can you at least show some sample input and what the expected output would be given the sample input

Comment: That's not a JSON "key value pair" that's a JSON object with properties, e.g. `x.word = "a"`, etc.

Comment: Please show us an example "page" and an idea of what it should look like once this process is done.

Comment: yes the properties of this object is a key value pair structure though. The point being, i can change my data structure if i need to, i just need the functionality of a key value pair.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Object.entries()` to get the key value pairs of an object.

```js
var words = [
  {"word":"a","votes":9326,"userMade":"FALSE","limiter":"FALSE"},
  {"word":"aaron","votes":4129,"userMade":"FALSE","limiter":"FALSE"}
];

words.forEach((wordEntry) => {
  var keyValuePairs = Object.entries(wordEntry);
  keyValuePairs.forEach((kv) => {
    console.log(`key: ${kv[0]} value: ${kv[1]}`);
  });
});
```

Comment: I don't know how my page structure is going to work with this. should I change words to a page number and iterate over the 200ish page variables? I could make the page number a value in the set, and check to see if it changes each time? is that efficient? am I missing something?

Comment: @TenZen I'm not sure what you mean with a page structure. Do you use some kind of pagination system?

Comment: I'm trying to append the word value to an html element that handles the 3d object this word is printed on. the user can see different pages (depicted in the example image) through controller inputs. so you see, when I am using my iterate to select the appropriate button, I need to also have a page reference. I was originally going to have that be the parent structure in which the sets of key value pares where nested, but I am not apposed to making the page number it's own key value pair if that's what it takes.

Comment: @TenZen Sorry it still is not clear to me what you mean. Can you provide a code example that reproduces your problem including the desired result?

Comment: we can use your code as the example of my problem, or the data structure i put above and just assume a for/in or for/of with a simple console.log for now. It only iterates over one page. i could  replace your var words with a page number, but than I would need around 200 of them, and then iterate over them. is that what I have to do?

Comment: the output would be an append code targeted at a specific button and a specific page given I'm guessing, 2 different iterate values. does that help?

Comment: Still not sure what you want. However you wont need to be worried about iterating over 200 items unless you do expensive operations in your loop. Normally it will be peanuts for any computer to iterate the items. If you have separate data for separate pages I would recommend to only retrieve the needed data for that page from the server.

Comment: thank you , i will take that answer. I thought it would be too WET, and I must be doing something wrong. As for managing the load, I was going to try and load the text in the background on a second worker with the visibility set to false until the appropriate page was activated. feel free to offer something better

Comment: I guess I should accept your answer? the clarification really was that I should do it in 2 stages  with some more wet code i guess, using variables as kind of an intermediary.

Answer (score 0):

my latest attempt looks like this:

```
for (let p=1; p<129; p++){
    for (let b=1; b<68; b++){
        let pTpl = (p).toLocaleString(undefined, {minimumIntegerDigits: 3});
        let bDbl = (b).toLocaleString(undefined, {minimumIntegerDigits: 2});
        var `#fCont${pTpl}${bDbl}` = document.createElement('a-text');
        `fCont${pTpl}${bDbl}`.setAttribute('value', 'engWordLib[p,b,0]');
        `fCont${pTpl}${bDbl}`.setAttribute('votes', 'engWordLib[p,b,1]');
        `fCont${pTpl}${bDbl}`.setAttribute('userMade', 'engWordLib[p,b,2]');
        `fCont${pTpl}${bDbl}`.setAttribute('limiter', 'engWordLib[p,b,3]');
        `fCont${pTpl}${bDbl}`.setAttribute('visible', 'false');
        `fBtn${bDbl}`.appendChild(`#fCont${pTpl}${bDbl}`)
    }
}
```

please note that I havent checked this for errors. I still think this code is to WET and I would prefer the key names for the properties be preserved in the datastructure rather than tacked on when it's appended to the page. I guess I could add a dimension to the array.... seems kind of messy when an object property value has the key value pairs right in it. cant get the iteration of objects in an array down though.... Will continue to persue a cleaner method.